# Responsive images resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a carousel of images inspired on the one in airbnb (https://www.airbnb.it/rooms/5382144?location=Roma%20Termini%2C%20Piazza%20dei%20Cinquecento%2C%20Roma%2C%20RM)

If you use the link above, you will notice the follows:

1. If you change the WIDTH of your window, the image will resize accordingly
2. If you change the HEIGHT of your window, the image will also resize accordingly
3. All the images are resized based on the height of the smallest image. That means that if I have two images, one in landscape and one in portrait, the portrait image will resize to fit the height of the landscape image.

Now, I've been able to achive the number 1 and 2, but I'm struggling to achieve the number 3 using just CSS.

I did a jsfiddle to show you what I'm talking about
https://jsfiddle.net/hvbvhc0q/5/

```
<div class="container">    
<div class="">
<div class="container-img">
 <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/67194098/f47fcd01_original.jpg?aki_policy=x_large" style="border: 2px solid blue">
  </div>

  <div class="container-img">
  <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/67194187/634b2de1_original.jpg?aki_policy=x_large" style="border: 2px solid red">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

.container-img img {
   position: absolute;
   max-height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

If you resize in width or height the preview box, you will notice that everything is perfectly responsive. But the problem is that the portrait image (red border) doesn't fit the landscape image (blu border). 
Said in other words: I want to keep the aspect ratio, but I want the portrait image to have the max-height equals to the height of the landscape (but of course without specifing any "fixed" height in px).

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: You would need js for that, css can't tell you which the smallest or largest image is, it is just for styling

Comment: Thanks for you answere @Pete! I was also thinking about that, but it seems that airbnb do this without any js. I tried to debug their css styles, But I coudn't find the "key" rule yet!

Comment: They seem to have **a lot** of media queries for every state and screen size to ensure that the images are all of a certain size given certain screen dimensions, they probably also start with the same size images so they are not having to resize based on different aspect ratios

Comment: I'm guessing you also want the portrait image to be covering the whole landscape (read: crop to fit?) or you don't mind seeing the landscape image underneat the other image?

Comment: @ArnoTenkink Yes, I wasnt' clear about that! Said in other words: I want the portrait image to have the max-height equals to the height of the landscape (but of course without specifing any "fixed" height in px). The width of the two images will remain different to keep the aspect ratio

Comment: @simonelucidi87 Ok, so that clear. You say 'specifying' any fixed height. But in your fiddle I see a fixed height of 300px within the container. Is that a dummy code or within your scope?

Comment: Ops! Dummy code! this is the right link https://jsfiddle.net/hvbvhc0q/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I don't now why it works, but I did it!! :D

Here you can find the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g8t2o9ft/6/
This is the code and css:

```
<div class="container">    
  <div  class="container-inner">
  <div>
  <div>
  <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/67194046/877580d4_original.jpg?aki_policy=xx_large" style="border: 2px solid blue">
  </div>
  <div>
  <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/67194187/634b2de1_original.jpg?aki_policy=x_large" style="border: 2px solid red">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

img {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;
}

.container-inner {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 65%;
}

.container {
max-width: 105vh;
}
```

As you can see, it's responsive for width (goal 1, easy), it's responive for height (goal 2, thanks to the rule max-width: 105vh) and the two images follow the same height keeping the same aspect ratio (goal 3).

Basically the trick that allows me to achieve the goal 3 is to apply these rules to the parent div:

```
.container-inner{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 65%;
}
```

But I still don't really know why it works (I copied it from airbnb css)

Thank you so much to everyone who answered this question!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what do you need, but, try this css code:

```
.container-img img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px; /*change for your necessity*/
}
```

But if you want to use a carousel component, I suggest for you that you research plugins js for this, like this link: https://github.com/yadhu/airbnb

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using bootstrap (correct me if I am wrong). If so use class img-responsive for the img tag as below.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Die-Bugger! Yes, I'm using bootstrap, but img-responsive seems to help me just for point 1 and 2, I still have problems achieving point 3

Comment: If point 3 works as you wish, won't your image lose its aspect ratio? Isn't the reason your portrait image takes the height of the landscape image?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clear about that! I want to keep the aspect ratio, I just want the portrait image to have the max-height equals to the height of the landscape (but of course without specifing any "fixed" height in px).

Comment: Isn't your container for img a fixed height based on media size? In one of my implementations, I used plain javascript to measure up the height based on media size and resize the container, which helped to resize the image of uniform size. However, a landscape image and portrait will still have different heights, but the container will hold them in a container of uniform height, which will have the look & feel not becoming an eye-sore.